# unity Asset Bundle 2

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, assetbundle

guys I need a help with Unity Asset Bundle I want to load my models from server like website, Google Drive (For Test) and also from Android mobile Internal or External Storage. Please Help me

Comment: so what is your question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This community is about questions regarding specific code related problems - **not** for doing code requests or "please code this for me" posts. Please go through [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and come back with a specific coding related issue providing a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

The recommended approach is to use the Addressable system. Learn about it here: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.addressables@0.4/manual/index.html

It's common to serve asset bundles from Amazon S3, but you have other options as well. I believe Unity has their own service now too.